# Sending two parse xml data files data into destination view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, xml-parsing, master-detail

I have successfully parsed two xml files and stored them into NSDictionary in master view controller. now when i want to send both files data into destination view controller, it doesn't work. I only able to pass one file at a time and two labels in destination view controller only get populated with one file data, not both. i also did create two instances of NSXml file.
To pass data into destination view controller from master view controller, i am doing this 
    `[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:[ _suraDict valueForKey:[_indexArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem2:[ _transDict valueForKey:[_indexArray2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]];`

In detail view controller, i have setDetailItem and setDetailItem2

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;
    [self configureView]; }

if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   } }
  - (void)setDetailItem2:(id)newDetailItem2
```

{

```
if (_detailItem2 != newDetailItem2) {
    _detailItem2 = newDetailItem2;
    [self configureView];}
if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) { 
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }}
```

And to populate data into labels

```
cell.contentTextView.text = [_detailItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.transView.text = [_detailItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. If you want to send both files in one go, then declare two variables (e.g. file1 and file2 ) in your destination View Controller that are of proper datatype. Something like this,

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* file1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* file2;
```

Now in your source View Controller, implement this method,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"])
{
   DestinationViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
    destController.file1 = @"file1_Data";
    destController.file2 = @"file2_Data";
}
}
```

In this method, basically you are setting the contents of both the files from the source View Controller itself and hence, you just have to use those variables to access the values in the destination View Controller.